# Convert 1.0 x 2^-140 to single precision floating point

Tags: floating-point, binary

So I'm trying to understand how I would convert such a number like 1.0 x 2^-140 in single floating point precision considering it is out of range. Any tips how I would go about solving this in binary?

Comment: Err... You convert it to zero. Did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to conversions like this and it's kind of confusing for me, so I'm trying to read along and do examples.

Comment: If this is IEEE-754 single precision, this number is exactly representable as a denormal. The relevant Wikipedia page seems to have enough information to let you figure out the encoding by yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format (hint: the encoding expressed as a hexadecimal integer is 0x00000200).